# Finding Menu ids of existing Modules in Odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I want to remove Customer menu from the Sales Module. So What I have done is that I created a Group named hidden group & am assigning it to Customer menu to hide it.. So My code is like this:-

```
<record model="res.groups" id="group_invisible">
            <field name="name">Hidden items</field>
        </record>

        <menuitem id="module_name.menuitem_id" parent="base.menu_sales" sequence="1" groups="group_invisible"/>
```

Here I want to find the parent value and id value of the menu.. So II given it here only I can hide it. So how can I find it from Odoo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Change the code like this:-

```
 <record model="res.groups" id="group_invisible">
            <field name="name">Hidden items</field>
        </record>

        <menuitem  id="base.menu_partner_form" parent="base.menu_sales" sequence="3" groups="group_invisible"/>
```

Here change the id to base.menu_partner_form  & parent to base.menu_sales.
You can find it by just searching for specific name like partner for Customer & using sequence id which u will get by searching in Menu items under developer tools. From the result we have to sort it out , which module it belongs to & all.

Comment: That works..perfectly for the scenario.. But still I have doubt how we can find for other menus..